# Fixed width on second td in editable table

Tags: html, css, html-table, contenteditable

I want to have a fixed width for my editable table, but I also wanting to set different width for each TD.
In my attempt I am able to get the table set at a fixed width, but this causes the width of the TDs appear to be 50% instead of the 80% - 20% I had before setting the fixed width

CSS

```
table {
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed td:nth-of-type(1) {width:20%;}
.fixed td:nth-of-type(2) {width:80%; text-align: left;}
.fixed {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;

    border:1px solid #000; }
.fixed td {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;
    border:1px solid #000; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed" contenteditable="true">
<table>
    <tbody>
<tr>
            <td colspan="2">Header:</td>

</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><br/></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DOB::</td>
            <td><br/></td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comments:</td>
            <td><br/></td>
</tr>

        </table>
```

What am I missing? Check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3dudbk/1/) if it will help. Try it out by typing enough to see it automatically goes to the next line after a certain point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your first `<tr>` is having `colspan="2"`. So when you give a `width:100%` to all the TDs of the table, the css won't get applied to the underlying TDs as you want.

Your solution is to separate the Header td: `<td colspan="2">Header:</td>` into a separate table (Refer HTML-1 below) 
**or** 
put the underlying TDs in the same TR as that of the header (Refer HTML-2 below).

Also change the CSS and simplify it like I did below. you have written a lot of unnecessary CSS.

**[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3dudbk/5/)**

Here's what I tried. try this:

**HTML-1:**

```
<table class="fixed" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header:</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table  class="fixed" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DOB::</td>
        <td>tes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Comments:</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**HTML-2:**

```
<table class="fixed" >
<tbody>
  <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header:</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DOB::</td>
        <td>tes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Comments:</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Simplified CSS:**

```
table {
  margin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.fixed td:nth-of-type(1) {width:80%;}
.fixed td:nth-of-type(2) {width:20%; text-align: left;}

.fixed td {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
border:1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. However, this is where I was stuck too, this allows me to change the table widths to 80% - 20% but makes it so it is not truly fixed width. If you want to test enter all the info you can into the second td and see it continues forever, and doesn't stop to go to the next line. I updated so you can test here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3dudbk/6/)

Comment: @Twaret As for the info text continuing forever, it will happen because your table is 100% width.  If you want truly fixed width then you should give a definite width to the table and NOT 100%. Give table width as 500px or 700px. If you give 100% will always take 100% width of the screen size or the parent element and it will keep expanding the width until the screen size.

Comment: Thanks! separating the first tr into it's own table allowed me to achieve both of my requirements. thank you very much sir! and thanks for the 100% width info as well.

Comment: @Twaret Please tick and accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Twaret Glad I could help. And use the simplified css as well. Better to have a simpler and cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

You have Errors in your html syntax although that is nothing to do with the problem.
See if you need something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3dudbk/2/).

```css
table {
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed td:nth-of-type(1) {width:20%;}
.fixed td:nth-of-type(2) {width:80%; text-align: left;}
.fixed {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;

    border:1px solid #000; }
.fixed td {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;
    border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<div class="fixed" contenteditable="true">
<table>
 <tbody>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">Header:</td>
   
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Name:</td>
   <td><br/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>DOB::</td>
   <td><br/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Comments:</td>
   <td><br/></td>
</tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table></div>
```

otherwise you wont be able to achieve variable td width as all the td will have same width in a column.
you can use colspan attribute for a workaround.